# Download gif from given URL

Tags: android, urlconnection

I'm trying to download GIF from given Url but there is a problem. I'm stuck here and don't know the correct way to download this file. How to repair this? I have sample url: http://i1.kwejk.pl/k/obrazki/2015/02/6f0239004a643dbd9510ebda5a6f22b3.gif

My code:

```
try{
            System.out.println(this.adressToGif);
            URL url = new URL(urltoGif);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            //conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); //IT crashes here and jumps to catch()
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bis.mark(conn.getContentLength());
            bis.close();

            gifPlayer = new NewGifPlayer(this, bis);

            //Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(bis);


        }catch(Exception x)
        {
            System.out.println("There is a problem");
        }
```

Comment: What is adressToGif and urltoGif?

Comment: I have udated post with URL.

Comment: Nothing wrong, are you sure urltoGif contains that exact url?

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run networking operations on the main thread. Use `AsyncTask` for that.