# Download GIF from URL

Tags: android

I don't know how to download a GIF from a given URL.
Downloading an image is trivial, but I had no success in downloading a GIF, so far.

I am using [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) to display GIFs, so I need the GIF as a Drawable.
While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454719/download-gif-from-given-url) is the same question, the code didn't work for me.

Comment: What was the problem with the code in that question??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif

Comment: @RajanBhavsar I'll try that. The ultimate solution would be getting the GIF as a Drawable, but I guess that would still do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this external library to download .gif image:-

https://github.com/koush/ion

This library supports animated GIFs image.

Hope It may helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external library Android-Universal-Image-Loader to download images from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: UIL doesn't support GIF files: [Please support gif](http://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/647).